# Control de excepciones en Node.js usando process.on( 'uncaughtException' )

Tags: javascript, nodejs, excepciones

Estoy intentando obtener el *Request* durante cuyo procesado se ha producido una excepción.

Este pequeño código de prueba se auto-lanza solicitudes HTTP y, dado un tiempo aleatorio, provoca una excepción:

```
const http = require( 'http' );

const Failto = Math.round( Math.random( ) * ( 25 - 10 ) + 10 );
var CurrRequest = 0;

console.log( 'Failto:', Failto );

process.on( 'uncaughtException', function( err ) {
  console.log( 'EXCEPTION:', {err} );
  process.exit( 0 );
} );

http.createServer( function( req, res ) {
  var idx;
  
  ++CurrRequest;
  idx = CurrRequest;

  console.log( 'Received request:', CurrRequest );
  setTimeout( function( ) {
    console.log( 'Sending response', idx );
    if( CurrRequest >= Failto ) { throw new Error( ); }
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.end( );
  }, Math.round( Math.random( ) * ( 2000 - 1000 ) + 1000 ) );
} ).listen( 8080 );

setInterval( function( ) {
  console.log( 'Sending request' );
  http.get( 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html', function( res ) {
  } ).on( 'finish', function( ) {
    console.log( 'Finish receive response' );
  } );
}, 200 );
```

Al lanzarse la excepción, se hace desde una *closure* concreta, con un valor único para `req`. Puedo tener varias *request* esperando, pero el error se ha generado durante el procesamiento de **una** en concreto. Y la excepción no me proporciona información sobre ello:

> EXCEPTION: {
> err: Error
>     at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/juanjo/test.js:22:41)
>     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
>     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
> }

Se que podría colocar `try { ... }` en mi código para capturar las excepciones y añadir manualmente la información que necesito, pero entonces:

- Siempre me quedaría la duda de si se me olvidó poner un `try` en alguna parte.
- Si uso algún *framework de nivel superior* (como `express`) y se provoca una excepción durante su código, no tendría la información que necesito.

La pregunta:

¿ Hay alguna forma, en el ejemplo expuesto, de obtener el `req` desde la función manejadora del evento `uncaughtException` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el evento [`request`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/http.html#http_event_request), para memorizar (crear una copia) de la solicitud en curso. Dicho evento se dispara cada vez que el servidor [`http`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/http.html) recibe una solicitud, por lo tanto, si ocurre una excepción durante el manejo de la misma, podrás obtener el valor de la solicitud que causó el problema.

Para implementarlo, debes crear la instancia del servidor que estás creando:

```
const server = http.createServer(...);
```

Luego usas el método `on()` y allí estableces la función que manejará el evento `request`, por ejemplo.

```
server.on('request', req => { ... });
```

En el manejador de evento podrías almacenar la lista de solicitudes que se van realizando, sin embargo es algo que no recomiendo, ya que pronto podrías agotar la memoria del equipo al tener que disponer un espacio para cada solicitud recibida.

Si lo que realmente necesitas saber es qué solicitud provocó la excepción, puedes almacenar una copia de la misma dentro de un objeto global.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let globalReq = {};
//...
server.on('request', req => {
  globalReq.request = req;
});
```

Haciendo estos pasos puedes tener el siguiente código:

```js
const http = require( 'http' );

const Failto = Math.round( Math.random( ) * ( 25 - 10 ) + 10 );
var CurrRequest = 1;
let globalReq = {};

console.log( 'Failto:', Failto );

process.on( 'uncaughtException', function( err ) {
  console.log( 'EXCEPTION:', {err} );
  console.log('Request Header was:');
  console.dir(globalReq.request.headers);
  process.exit( 0 );
} );


const server = http.createServer( function( req, res ) {
  let idx;
  
  idx = CurrRequest++;
 
  console.log( 'Received request:', idx );
  setTimeout( function( ) {
    console.log( 'Sending response', idx );
    if( idx >= Failto ) { throw new Error( ); }
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.end( );
  }, Math.round( Math.random( ) * ( 2000 - 1000 ) + 1000 ) );
} ).listen( 8080 );

server.on('request', req => {
  globalReq.request = req;
});

setInterval( function( ) {
  console.log( 'Sending request' );
  http.get( 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html', {headers: {'X-Request-ID': CurrRequest}}, function( res ) {
  } ).on( 'finish', function( ) {
    console.log( 'Finish receive response' );
  } );
}, 200 );
```

En la solicitud realizada a mi servidor he añadido la cabecera `X-Request-ID`, con la cual pretendo identificar la solicitud.

Cuando se captura la excepción, muestro por pantalla la cabecera de la solicitud correspondiente (la que fue almacenada en el campo `request` de mi objeto `globalReq`). Con esto compruebo que efectivamente la solicitud almacenada en dicho objeto es la que causa la excepción.

Una salida probable de este código puede ser:

```sh
Received request: 15
Sending response 7
EXCEPTION: {
  err: Error
      at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/mauricio/stackoverflow/376163/index.js:25:41)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
}
Request Header was:
{ 'x-request-id': '14', host: '127.0.0.1:8080', connection: 'close' }
```

Tal vez necesites mirar un poco el tema del conteo de las solicitudes, pero en términos generales coincide con el resultado esperado.

No sé si es exactamente lo que estás buscando, ya que esta implementación requiere 2 cosas:

1. Crear un objeto global para almacenar una copia de la solicitud en proceso.
2. Usar el evento `request` de la instancia del servidor.

Es lo más sencillo que se me ocurre basado en el código que presentas en la pregunta. En todo caso, es igualmente una forma manual de hacer las cosas, y aunque podrías siempre *olvidar* hacerlo, esto es simplemente una de esas cosas que escribes una vez y funciona para todas las solicitudes.

Comment: ¡¡¡  !!! ¡¡¡ You are **THE** boss !!!